# JMeter HTTP Test Script Recorder randomly stops recording

Tags: jmeter

I am creating recordings for a company website for performance tests. Normally this works fine though on occasion when starting a new test recording, HTTP Test Script Recorder will not record anything but returns the following error in the browser:
[image]

I have been using jmeter for a while now so I know the setup for HTTP Test Script Recorder is ok.
Clearing browser history, running in public or private mode doesn't help. Re-issuing jmeter proxy cert makes no difference either, the same for deleting proxyserver.jks.
Having experienced this before, I know that after a few days HTTP Test Script Recorder will start working again. 
Happens for both jmeter v4 & v5.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Could you describe exactly how you are getting this ? did you for example previously use the same JMeter instance for a load test or something else ? Is there some kind of authentication happening ? What type ? If you can describe issue, a bug could be created to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I have used the same JMeter instance to record & execute test plans. Using config elements HTTP Header Manager/Request Defaults/DNS Cache/Authorization Manager/Cookie Manager & Cache Manager......normally works without issue. So if I restart everything (so it's clean) follow the standard process for recording, occasionally I get this error described above.

Comment: ok, I was about to provide a full debug log, though now I am not receiving that error message. Instead I have no recorded data when logging in (when error message was received), a couple of requests based on random clicks and then nothing. As this is not the first time I've seen this, I will provide a full log when it re-occurs. As of now I have a different issue, though I suspect it is a symptom of what I originally posted.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, issue only re-occurred this morning. As suggested I raised a bug  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62916

Comment: The bug you reported has now been fixed, as per my updated answer, you can test nightly build, so can you please test and if ok accept answer and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can think only of one situation when it can happen:

1. You have a JMeter test running in background (or a thread which failed to stop for some reason)
2. You're trying to record something at the same time

So

- Make sure that nothing is running at the moment (you should see `0/0` in upper right corner of JMeter GUI)

  [image: JMeter 0 active threads]
- Start clean recording session, to wit restart JMeter and create the test plan using [Recording Template feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) (From main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

  [image: JMeter REcording Template]

---

Just in case be aware that you can also record your mobile application traffic using cloud-based proxy service, as a bonus you will get possibility to export recorded scripts in **SmartJMX** mode with automated detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details if interested.

Comment: On point 1.  this already occurred to me. I use a master/slave setup so bounced jmeter-server on all without success. On point 2. no other recordings are taking place. Concerning SmartJMX, as this is blazemeter (which will require an upload to them) and what I need to record contains a number of usernames/passwords, when I questioned Blazemeter about security I didn't get any guarantee that passwords would be secured. And logs don't show anything, only HTTP TEST Script Recorder started.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you see is most probably a bug probably introduced by:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57962

During recording, JMeter variables are null so we end up using an Unmodifiable version of them because of this:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.java#L88

I suggest you open a bug here, providing as much information as possible:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Provide:

- How you reproduce it
- The jmeter.log with the stacktrace (not as an image)

The workaround is to avoid running a test and recording after that.

**Edit on 3 december 2018:**

You reported a bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62916

The reproducer is:

- Start a distributed test where Controller is in GUI mode and a jmeter-server
- Once test is finished, start a Recording using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
- Hit a URL, you'll get the issue

**The bug has been fixed today, it will be available in JMeter 5.1 and is already available in:**

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/jmeter/nightlies/